# Printing out a concatenated string shows (null)

Tags: ios, objective-c, string

I want to create a string in the following format: `id[]=%@&stringdata[]=%@&id[]=%@&stringdata[]=%@&id[]=%@&stringdata[]=%@&` etc. in the for loop i get the id and stringdata, but when I print out the testString is says (null), however when I print out the Ident and Stringdata seperate (the first two NSLogs) the id does get printed out right, stringdata shows also (null) because the strings are empty at that moment so thats normal.

```
for(NSUInteger i = 0; i<self.childViewControllers.count; i++) {

        NSLog(@"Ident: %@",((myViewController*)[self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:i]).ident);
        NSLog(@"Stringdata: %@",((myViewController*)[self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:i]).getQAnswer);

        testString = [testString stringByAppendingString:([NSString stringWithFormat: @"id[]=%@&stringdata[]=%@&",((myViewController*)[self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:i]).ident ,((myViewController*)[self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:i]).getQAnswer])];

        NSLog(@"PostString : %@",testString);
}
```

Comment: Dont use NSString *testString, use NSMutableString and dont forget to alloc+init

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that `testString` is `nil` when you go into this loop. So every time you call `stringByAppendingString:`, you're passing that to a `nil` object, which does nothing. At the end of the loop, `testString` is still `nil.`

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableString *mString = [NSMutableString string];
for(NSUInteger i = 0; i<self.childViewControllers.count; i++)
{
    [mString appendFormat:@"%@id[]=%@",(i>0)?@"&":@"",((myViewController*)[self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:i]).ident];
    [mString appendFormat:@"&stringdata[]=%@",((myViewController*)[self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:i]).getQAnswer];
}
NSLog(@"PostString : %@",mString);
```

hope this helps

using test strings it outputs:

> 2013-04-04 23:46:54.619 PagingScrollView[93543:c07] PostString :
>   id[]=TESTI&stringdata[]=TESTQ&id[]=TESTI&stringdata[]=TESTQ&id[]=TESTI&stringdata[]=TESTQ&id[]=TESTI&stringdata[]=TESTQ&id[]=TESTI&stringdata[]=TESTQ&id[]=TESTI&stringdata[]=TESTQ&id[]=TESTI&stringdata[]=TESTQ&id[]=TESTI&stringdata[]=TESTQ&id[]=TESTI&stringdata[]=TESTQ&id[]=TESTI&stringdata[]=TESTQ

Answer (score 0):

You're appending that format on `testString`. As it was not initialized, it's `nil` and any message to `nil` returns `nil`.

You should use:

```
testString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"id[]=%@&stringdata[]=%@&",((myViewController*)[self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:i]).ident ,((myViewController*)[self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:i]).getQAnswer];
```